# cocos2dx - Bypass body contact

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, game-physics, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I am using **cocos2dx** and setup two Sprites with same Physics Body definitions see below

```
PhysicsBody *physicsBody=PhysicsBody::createBox(size,PhysicsMaterial(1.0f,0.0,0.5f),Vec2(0, size.height*0.5));
physicsBody->setGravityEnable(true);
physicsBody->setCategoryBitmask(1);
physicsBody->setCollisionBitmask(1);
physicsBody->setContactTestBitmask(true);
physicsBody->setDynamic(true);
physicsBody->setContactTestBitmask(0xFFFFFFFF);
physicsBody->setMass(5.0f);
node->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody);
```

I am defining a `collision detection` between both the physics bodies

```
auto contactListener=EventListenerPhysicsContactWithBodies::create(player1->getPhysicsBody(), player2->getPhysicsBody());

contactListener->onContactBegin = CC_CALLBACK_1(Game::onPlayerContact, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(contactListener, this);
```

**I don't want these two bodies to collide with each other or, any effect of physics if they collide.** I am doing

```
bool Game::onPlayerContact(cocos2d::PhysicsContact &contact){
    auto nodeA = contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->getNode();
    auto nodeB = contact.getShapeB()->getBody()->getNode();

    if(nodeA != NULL && nodeB != NULL){

        printf("\nPlayers collided");

    }

    return false;
}
```

**I am not able to bypass the contact between two bodies, what else should be done to avoid collision?**

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Collision filtering allows you to prevent collision between shapes. Cocos2d-x supports collision filtering using category and groups bitmasks.

Cocos2d-x supports 32 collision categories. For each shape you can specify which category it belongs to. You also specify what other categories this shape can collide with. This is done with masking bits. For example:

```
auto sprite1 = addSpriteAtPosition(Vec2(s_centre.x - 150,s_centre.y));
sprite1->getPhysicsBody()->setCategoryBitmask(0x02);    // 0010
sprite1->getPhysicsBody()->setCollisionBitmask(0x01);   // 0001

auto sprite3 = addSpriteAtPosition(Vec2(s_centre.x + 150,s_centre.y + 100),2);
sprite3->getPhysicsBody()->setCategoryBitmask(0x03);    // 0011
sprite3->getPhysicsBody()->setCollisionBitmask(0x03);   // 0011
```

then in your collision callback. Do this.

```
if ((shapeA->getCategoryBitmask() & shapeB->getCollisionBitmask()) == 0
   || (shapeB->getCategoryBitmask() & shapeA->getCollisionBitmask()) == 0)
{
   // shapes can't collide
   ret = false;
}
```

source : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics

Comment: I don't think the last piece of code is correct; in the Cocos2d-x wiki, that is just given as an example of checking if two bodies could possibly collide.  By setting the masks the way you do, you won't see those 2 bodies colliding in the collision callback, which is the entire point you are making, isn't it?

Comment: @sanchitgulati how my code is different from yours, I am too telling the contact delegate to `bypass and returning false;` does the collision and category bit mask do something?

Comment: this link is for box2d but follows the same concept http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Queries Under the Physics
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics
Perhaps the Point Query..

Basically the Box2d has sensors which are used to detect contact and not any collision...
i recommend using Box2d over Cocos2d Physics...It is much Better..